# Terraform variables within variables

Tags: terraform

First off - apologies - I’m extremely new (3 hours in!) to using terraform.

I am looking to try and use the value of a variable inside the declaration of another variable.

Below is my code - what am I doing wrong?

**variables.tf:**

```
variable "EnvironmentName" {
    type = "string"
}
variable "tags" {
    type = "map"
    default = {
        Environment = "${var.EnvironmentName}"
        CostCentre = "C1234"
        Project = "TerraformTest"
        Department = "Systems"
    }
}
```

**Variables-dev.tfvars:**

```
EnvShortName = "Dev"
EnvironmentName = "Development1"
#Location
Location = "westeurope"
```

**main.tf:**

```
resource “azurerm_resource_group” “TestAppRG” {
    name = “EUW-RGs-${var.EnvShortName}”
    location = “${var.Location}”
    tags = “${var.tags}”
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error: Variables not allowed on variables.tf  line 18, in variable
>   “tags”: 18: Environment = “${var.EnvironmentName}”
>   Variables may not be used here.

I understand that the error message is fairly self explanatory and it is probably my approach that is wrong - but how do I use a variable in the definition of another variable map? is this even possible?

I will be standing up multiple resources - so want the tags to be built as a map and be passed into each resource - but I also want to recycle the map with other tfvars files to deploy multiple instances for different teams to work on.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Terraform does not support variables inside a variable. If you want to generate a value based on two or more variables then you can try [Terraform locals](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals).

You can define the `locals` like this:

```
locals {
  tags = {
    Environment = "${var.EnvironmentName}"
    CostCentre  = "C1234"
    Project     = "TerraformTest"
    Department  = "Systems"
  }
}
```

And then you can access them using `local.tags`:

```
resource “azurerm_resource_group” “TestAppRG” {
  name     = “EUW-RGs-${var.EnvShortName}”
  location = “${var.Location}”
  tags     = “${local.tags}”
}
```

Comment: but we need to define this in each module, how if I have to achieve for entire platform and I have different modules for resources , should I create this in each module main.tf file ?

Comment: You can reference multiple modules in a root module & in the root module, (where you run terraform apply) is where you can set your locals. Look at this example here in my repository: https://github.com/pgreene/terraform-aws-rds-cluster-plan Terraform reads all *.tf files as one. So how you organize them is up to you. You see locals.tf is referenced in multiple resources (modules) in main.tf

Comment: what if I need to access a map inside a var in the locals like `format("%s-subnet", var.environment)["address"]`? You will get invalid index since the variable is known only after apply. Is it possible to use output vars or explicit dependencies here?

Comment: Do you mean accessing a `map` type variable in the `locals`? One way to do is like this -  format("%s-webserver", var.labels["environment"])
Let's say you have a map variable ```labels = {
  "environment" = "dev"
  "team"        = "devops"
  "application" = "webserver"
}
``` , then you can use that in locals like this ```locals {
  name = format("%s-webserver", var.labels["environment"])
}```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use locals to do the sort of transform you are after

**variables.tf:**

```
variable "EnvironmentName" {
    type = "string"
}
```

**locals.tf**

```
locals {
  tags = {
      Environment = var.EnvironmentName
      CostCentre = "C1234"
      Project = "TerraformTest"
      Department = "Systems"
  }
}
```

**Variables-dev.tfvars:**

```
EnvShortName = "Dev"
EnvironmentName = "Development1"
#Location
Location = "westeurope"
```

**main.tf:**

```
resource “azurerm_resource_group” “TestAppRG” {
    name = “EUW-RGs-${var.EnvShortName}”
    location = var.Location
    tags = local.tags
}
```

You can do things like `tags = merge(local.tags,{"key"="value"}) to extend your tags.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to this question, as it often referred from a google request for a similar questions about how to "*terraform local value based on another variable*", here is the way which can be useful and related for such requests.

In case when you have one constant var which you can't change for a particular module (let's say `var.env`) and you need to have another local value either 0 or 1 based on that variable value, then you need kind of switch based on another value. To achieve so in place:

```
env_prefix = var.env == "dev" ? "np" : "pd"
```

In this case `env_prefix` will be `np` if `var.env` has value equal `dev`. Otherwise `env_prefix` will be `pd`