# How can I override locals in terraform?

Tags: terraform, local-variables

I have a locals block in `module-1` and want to override that on dev/variables.tf

I tried everything but nothing worked. As I'm using multiple variables in this locals block, I need to keep it that way instead of converting to a variable. How can I accomplish that?

```
├── _modules
│   ├── module-1
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf   
└── env
    ├── dev
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   └── variables.tf
    ├── staging
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   └── variables.tf
```

As per [this doc](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/files/override), I also tried using override.tf file but it didn't override the block.

ChatGPT says locals cannot be overwritten outside of the module if it's true. In this case, what would be the best practise to replace a block in terraform? As I mentioned, I'm using multiple variables in this block and can't use a variable for it, but in the meantime, I want to overwrite this block not to repeat myself. :thinking:

Edit:

_modules/module-1/variables.tf

```
...
...
variable "host_address" {
  type    = string
}

locals {
  health_checks = {
    checks-1 = {
      api_name        = "Name X"
      api_method      = "GET"
      host            = var.host_address
      custom_headers  = {
        Content-Type      = "application/json"
      }
    }
    checks-2 = {
      api_name        = "Name Y"
      api_method      = "POST"
      host            = var.host_address
      custom_headers  = {
        Content-Type      = "application/json"
      }
    }
    # Add more checks as needed


  }
}
```

_modules/module-1/main.tf

```
...
...
resource "checkly_check" "health-checks" {
  for_each                  = local.health_checks
  name                      = "${var.environment} - ${each.value.api_name}"
  host                      = "${each.value.host_address}"
  # ...

}
```

Basically, this locals should be overwritten in env/dev, env/staging etc.

Edit 2:

env/dev/variables.tf

```
...
...
variable "host_address" {
  type    = string
}
locals {
  health_checks = {
    checks-1 = {
      api_name        = "Name Dev Test"
      api_method      = "GET"
      host            = var.host_address
      custom_headers  = {
        Content-Type      = "application/json"
      }
    }
}
```

env/staging/variables.tf

```
...
...
variable "host_address" {
  type    = string
}
variable "main_domain" {
  type    = string
}
locals {
  health_checks = {
    checks-1 = {
      api_name        = "Name Staging Test"
      api_method      = "GET"
      host            = var.host_address
      custom_headers  = {
        Content-Type      = "application/json"
      }
    checks-2 = {
      api_name        = "Name Staging Test 2"
      api_method      = "GET"
      host            = var.main_domain
      custom_headers  = {
        Content-Type      = "application/json"
      }
    }
}
    checks-3 = {
      api_name        = "Name Staging Test 3"
      api_method      = "GET"
      host            = "www.anything.com"
      custom_headers  = {
        Content-Type      = "application/json"
      }
    }
}
```

When I add locals to env folders, terraform doesn't respect that, it only refers to the local in modules, which I understand because local doesn't go outside of modules. And I can't use variables because I need to refer to other variables in this block. That's why I used local. So what would be the best approach to this?

Comment: maybe share the locals block and what your trying to override it with. As you have mentioned you cannot override locals. So you will need some other method to handle this

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just added some template for clarity. @ChrisDoyle

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the replacement data would look like? I can think of a few ways to handle this. 1) have the healthchecks for different envs in the local under that env, so you can then say `loca.health_checks[var.env]` and get the health checks for that env. However that doesnt scale very well. The better approach would be to allow the calling code to pass the healthchecks it wants. once i see what the replacement data looks like and how it would be passed I will write an answer.

Comment: Based on your description in the question these `local` should be `variables` with `default` values assigned to the values in `local`, and then the module declaration parameter values would either override or fallback to the defaults.

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard I tried this method, but it terraform doesn't allow you to refer to another variable within a variable. So that's why I used local actually.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I added Edit 2 in the post for your comment.

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard when I do that, this is the error I get,
 Error: Variables not allowed
host            = var.host_address
│ Variables may not be used here.

Comment: You do not need to resolve a variable's value within that variable's defaults because the `host_address` is part of that variable's structure and therefore would be assigned its own default. The current declaration both is and would be superfluous.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't provide the full context, but the reason behind that is that host_address might change, so in another check it might refer to `var.main_domain`. I updated the post @MatthewSchuchard

Comment: Ok so you have a few options here to remove the `local` and use a `variable` declaration. The path forward (which may also be @ChrisDoyle mention of paseudo-data) depends on the logic determining the `host` value.

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard thanks for your comment. Do you mean an `if` logic in the module? Because host value can be anything that doesn't necessarily depend on a variable. Let's say I switched to variable, how can I make use of variable within a variable? As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58841060/terraform-variables-within-variables), I can't use a variable within a variable. In that case, how should the logic be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257155/discussion-between-cosmos-1905-14-and-matthew-schuchard).

Comment: I agree with @MatthewSchuchard that these should be variables of the module to allow the module be re-useable and composable. This was each env can define its own health checks.

Answer (score 1):

So personally I am also with Matthews view in the comments. that this should be a variable for the module. It should just provide the abstraction of what a health check is. Then the envs should pass in the health checks they want. You can even define common healthcheck that might be required in all envs.

**foo module**

```
variable "health_checks" {
  type = map(object({
    api_name       = string
    api_method     = string
    host           = string
    custom_headers = map(string)
  }))
}

output "checks" {
  value = var.health_checks
}
```

Then in your root module you could have something like

```
variable "host_address" {
  type = string
}

locals {
  common_health_checks = {
    checks-1 = {
      api_name       = "Name X"
      api_method     = "GET"
      host           = var.host_address
      custom_headers = {
        Content-Type = "application/json"
      }
    }
  }
}

module "prod" {
  source        = "./modules/foo"
  health_checks = merge(local.common_health_checks, {
    checks-B = {
      api_name       = "Name Y"
      api_method     = "POST"
      host           = "example.com"
      custom_headers = {
        Content-Type = "application/json"
      }
    }
  })
}

module "dev" {
  source = "./modules/foo"
  health_checks = merge(local.common_health_checks,{
    checks-A = {
      api_name       = "Name Z"
      api_method     = "GET"
      host           = var.host_address
      custom_headers = {
        Content-Type = "application/json"
      }
    }
  })
}


output "prod" {
  value = module.prod.checks
}

output "dev" {
  value = module.dev.checks
}
```

So each env then passes its own healthchecks but can also use common ones etc. This gives an output like below and you can see different envs can have different checks or common ones

```
Outputs:

dev = tomap({
  "checks-1" = {
    "api_method" = "GET"
    "api_name" = "Name X"
    "custom_headers" = tomap({
      "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    })
    "host" = "foo.com"
  }
  "checks-A" = {
    "api_method" = "GET"
    "api_name" = "Name Z"
    "custom_headers" = tomap({
      "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    })
    "host" = "foo.com"
  }
})
prod = tomap({
  "checks-1" = {
    "api_method" = "GET"
    "api_name" = "Name X"
    "custom_headers" = tomap({
      "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    })
    "host" = "foo.com"
  }
  "checks-B" = {
    "api_method" = "POST"
    "api_name" = "Name Y"
    "custom_headers" = tomap({
      "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    })
    "host" = "example.com"
  }
})
```